# How to get id field with group by in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-filter

I am trying to fetch group by data in Django. I`m using postgres database
How I Can write Django query like this SQL query:-

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE name=%s GROUP BY name"
```

I am trying with `Model.objects.filter().values('id').annotate(count=Count('name')).order_by('name')` but not get unique name`s id in QuerySet

and also try
`Product.objects.filter(id__in=RawSQL(f"SELECT id FROM product_product WHERE name=%s GROUP BY name", (key,)))`

but got error

`"column \"product_product.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function\nLINE 1: ..._product\" WHERE \"product_product\".\"id\" IN (SELECT id FROM pr...`

Answer (score 0):

```
model.objects.filter(user=id).values('name').annotate(dcount=Count('name')).order_by()
```

- You need to specify a filter value when u want to filter data from the model.
- The value field takes in the value you want not the id
- Then you annotate it.

For more information you can read the django documentation: [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-%5Daggregation)

Comment: Thank you for replying. from this query I'm getting only unique names. I want the name and id from this query. please suggest how I to get id and name fields with the GROUP BY. like this MySQL query `SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE name=%s GROUP BY name`

Comment: for id and name I tried `Model.objects.filter(name=a_name).values('id', 'name').annotate(count=Count(field)).order_by()` but not getting unique names

Comment: I also tried `Product.objects.filter(name=key).values(field).annotate(
                count=Coalesce('id', field, output_field=CharField()),
            ).order_by(field)` and also not getting unique name with id

Comment: can you share the model in which you are trying this query?

Comment: `class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=100)
class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name="review")
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=62000, null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1.0), 
                        MaxValueValidator(5.0)],)`

Comment: try this: model.objects.filter(user=id).values('name').annotate(dcount=Count('name')).all()

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem? I'm facing the same where I want to get more fileds like `SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE name=%s GROUP BY name`